# Custom, self hosted Android Marketplace

Tags: android

I did some research and i can't find a proper custom marketplace solution for Android, i would like to know if someone knows any, with the possibility of being hosted and maintained by us, and fully customizable.

I read about F-Droid but it doesn't seems to be very customizable, as far as i know.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Well you have a few options. We built our own app store at the last contract I was in. From a file storage it was pretty straight forward. For Android we just supported unknown devices at first, but later switched to integrated MDM(Mobile Device Management) system. I can't remember exactly which one we landed on in the end.

However, for the iOS side we had to build SSL pointers that are nested in a manifest file that points to the IPA. For Android, we just had to sign and place the APK. For Web packages, we hosted an internal NPM server.

For the packages we used Apache Archiva, but that is not the same thing, so just tossing that out there if it matters at all to you.

Lastly, we built an Angular based web interface to handle Authentication and displaying of available apps/versions. Lastly we built an app to put on the app store that others would install that would keep up with our services to know what was installed, needed upgraded, or uninstalled.

However, this took a team of engineers over a year to get done.
So let's talk free options. Just google Android Market Place self hosted alternatives. Last year at the CES I met with Aptoid and they were deploying many self hosted, self managed options that would fit your need very nicely. I don't remember the exact pricing though.

So bottom line is, depends on how fancy you want to get and if you have time to build your own, or if you want to buy/subscribe to one out of the box.

Hope that helps.